# Skip maven phases in the forked lifecycle of plugins in Maven 3

Tags: java, maven

Most coverage plugins fork a lifecycle to prevent mixing up the instrumented byte code and the production code. Maven seems to force any lifecycle to perform completely till the specified phase, so the in the lifecycles that coverage plugins fork often execute all phases that are prior to `test`.

It seems only the `compile` phase is really needed for this forked lifecycle because everything else is completely the same as the original lifecycle, e.g., `checkstyle` plugin, `generate-sources`, `test-compile`, and others. Running these phases repeatedly also takes a lot of extra time when the project is large.

So, in general, or in the above case, is there any way to let the forked lifecycle to skip some phases that are not necessary?

Comment: What kind of coverage tool/Maven plugin do you use? Apart from that instrumented code is for code coverage not really needed...

Comment: maven-scoverage-plugin it is. Yes, I need to run coverage, so instrumented code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip phases. There are ways of skipping some plugin executions bound to a phase (for instance -Dmaven.test.skip=true or -DskipTests=true).

You could also call a plugin goal directly, but I do not know if that would work for your particular case.

`mvn plugin-group-id:plugin-artifact-id:plugin-goal`

Comment: I don't really want to skip plugins completely. I want to skip the plugins when the lifecycle is forked by another plugin. Also, test-compile is not a plugin, but it is redundant when maven runs it twice.